# Is it possible to Reverse Engineer digitially signed android game & then repack it

Tags: android

I am a noob in this field. I have reverse engineered an Android game to hack it but I can only install the game if it was not digitally signed.

If the game is digitally signed, I am unable to install it on my android device (No root device). I know that signature verification can be bypassed in root devices. But I need to know that could it de done in No Root devices?

Please point me in right direction

Answer (score 1):

You can disable trusted source application limitation through the settings menu for every mobile device you want the application executed on, and then you should self-sign your application.

[This](http://www.androiddevelopment.org/tag/apk/) blog post explains how to self-sign an apk